# What is the core in the elder wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

The core of a wand greatly influences how easy it is to master and how easily it will bend its allegiance to a new owner. Is it ever mentioned what core was used in the elder wand? I'm pretty sure it's never mentioned in the books, and in “Tales of Beedle the Bard” it is just said that the wand was fabricated and there's no other detail. Is it mentioned in other official sources, such as author interviews?

Alternatively, if this does not have a definite answer, I would also be interested in a  logical speculation of what the core might be, based on what we do know about the various wand core types, their characteristics, and the characteristics shown by the elder wand.

Comment: I wonder - does this mean the 'original' elder wand? Didn't Malfoy's wand 'become' the elder wand after he defeated Dumbledore?

Comment: @NKCampbell `"Didn't Malfoy's wand 'become' the elder wand after he defeated Dumbledore?"` No. Malfoy became the _master_ of the Elder Wand when he disarmed Dumbledore, meaning the wand would serve Malfoy the most effectively should Malfoy ever actually get a chance to use it. The Elder Wand doesn't reincarnate itself into other wands.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**A thestral tail hair.**

From [J.K. Rowling’s website](https://web.archive.org/web/20080219064944/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=25):

> I decided that the core of the Elder Wand is the tail hair of a Thestral; a powerful and tricky substance that can be mastered only by a witch or wizard capable of facing death.

This is backed up by a comment in an interview:

> **MA:** Speaking of the Elder Wand...
>
> **JKR:** Yeah?
>
> **MA:** Can we talk about wandlore a little bit?
>
> **JKR**: Oh, absolutely. Oh, thestrals – I noticed there was immediate angst about the fact that there was a thestral hair in the middle of the Elder Wand. People were saying, “but Hagrid bred thestrals,” but no, he didn't. He just bred the Hogwarts thestrals. Just to make that clear.
>
> — [Pottercast interviews J.K. Rowling, part two, December 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1224-pottercast-anelli.html)

(Note: The people saying “but Hagrid bred thestrals” meant in the sense that he bred them *from scratch*, creating the breed entirely himself.)

Comment: But why is it not in the official right now? Is it because the site is down or because J. K. Rowling changed her mind after posting it?

Comment: @user13267: JK Rowling’s site has been restructured multiple times. Old links regularly stop working. But nothing posted there has ever been officially retracted, afaik.

Comment: Oh JKR.... if Hargrid bred the Hogwarts thestrals, I'd say he bred thestrals. Unless the Hogwarts thestrals were somehow a different breed or species of thestral.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: I believe she was replying to people who thought Hagrid bred *all* Thestrals, like he bred the Blast-Ended Skrewts from scratch. He *bred* Thestrals, but he didn’t *create* them.

Comment: ...people thought Hagrid *created* thestrals? My goodness. I suppose he invented spiders too.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: Yep. I didn’t include that part of the interview here, but the next few lines make it pretty clear that's what she meant.

Comment: Hagrid bred the Blast-Ended Skrewts *from scratch*? TIL...

Comment: @Michael If I remember correctly, they were a crossbreed of Manticores and Fire Crabs...